# Set shell environment variable without using a shell builtin command

Tags: shell-builtin

I am using a program that takes a "command" as an argument and then adds some helpful wraping around it. Presumably in an effort to be helpful it appears to checks to make sure the command "exists". As far as I can tell this check is something like `which`. In my bash shell commands like `set` and `export` are built in and therefore `which` doesn't return anything.

Is there a way to set an environment variable without using a shell builtin.

My thought was to do something like define `set.sh` to be

```
#! /bin/bash
export $1
```

but this seems mildly crazy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Only the shell can change its own environment; `set` and `export` *must* always be built-ins.

This is also true of `cd`, `alias` and so on.

The best I can suggest is to reimplement your wrapper using a shell function. Either that or a shell script that you "source". Either way, a wrapper that runs *inside* the shell can do these things more seemlessly.

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround for your original problem would be a wrapper for your wrapper (Xzibit image not included):

```
#!/bin/bash

command="$1"
temp=$(mktemp -d)

> "$temp/$command"
chmod a+x "$temp/$command"

PATH+=:$temp

your_wrapper

rm -r "$temp"
```

This creates an empty executable which will pass your wrapper's tests without overriding the command that you *actually* want to run (the builtin).